# How to print task name in gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a question about gradle. I'am a newbie in this build system and want to know about how to print task name or save it in a variable.

Something like this:

```
> gradle someTask

someTask
```

i think code is like this

```
task someTask {
   print ($arg[0])
}
```

but it is not.

Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you want, but you can get the taskNames that were used when Gradle was called by accessing the `project.gradle` object.

ie:  given the following `build.gradle`

```
task someTask << {
    println project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames
}
```

Then running:

```
gradle someTask someTask
```

Gives the output:

```
:someTask
[someTask, someTask]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.34 secs
```

**Update;** if anyone needs actual-check instead of just logging, try:

```
def myTaskName = 'someTask'

if (project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(myTaskName)) {
    println "Handle ${myTaskName} here."
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's not what i want.
At first i made a mistake when i edit a text.
Of course i want to

    in>  gradle someTask
    out> someTask


In and Out it means command line

Comment: Oh, i really can't understand how to clearly write what i want. Thanks anyway, you are great!

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the name of the currently running task?

Comment: Yes, may be, but i think it works only for one task. I want to see the task that write in command line.

Comment: `project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames` is a list of all the task names called at the command line

Comment: @VitaliQ fyi, to get the name of the currently running task within a task closure, you can use `${it.name}`

Comment: You could try using gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("<some name>") ... and you can try first using println on this list. This would be a first solution towards a prettier one..

Comment: Saved me today! Thanks a lot! I'm adding properties only if a given task has been scheduled to run :)

Answer (score 4):

AFAIU, you need this:

```
task someTask << {
  println ${name}
}
```