# How to print the current task name in gradle

Tags: gradle

Is there a way where I can get the details of the current task being executed? For example I want to print the name of the current task being executed, etc.

I tried this :

```
task printMyNameIfYouCan << {
    println $task.name
}
```

But it fails with

```
Execution failed for task ':printMyNameIfYouCan'.
> Could not find property '$task' on task ':printMyNameIfYouCan'.
```

NOTE: I checked [How to print task name in gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603257/how-to-print-task-name-in-gradle), but this is not I'm looking at.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
task printMyNameIfYouCan {
    doLast {
        println name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask {
    Task task,TaskState state ->
        if (state.failure) {    println "$task.name FAILED"}
        else               {    println "$task.name SUCCESSFULL"}
}
```