# Gradle tasks with different sourcesets

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have two tasks, `jar` and `run`, that both depend on the `build` task. When `jar` is called I would like it to build only files in a specific folder. Then when `run` is called I would like it to build the same files that `jar` did plus files from an additional folder.

Here's a sudo-code example:

```
jar.build.sourcesets += 'my/path/to/files'
run.build.sourcesets += jar.build.sourcesets
run.build.sourcesets += 'additonal/path/to/files'
```

Here's what I have right now in my `build.gradle` file that isn't working:

```
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    run.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin' 
    run.resources.srcDirs += "src/main/resources"
    run.resources.srcDirs += "src/test/resources" 
    run.output.resourcesDir = "build/js/resources"
}
```

I've been reading about sourcesets but I haven't found a solution yet. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a few more hours of searching I found the solution at this link:
[How to print task name in gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603257/how-to-print-task-name-in-gradle)

I can use the `taskNames` array at runtime to check to see what task was called.

```
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'

    if(project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("run")) {
        main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
        main.resources.srcDirs += "src/main/resources"
        main.resources.srcDirs += "src/test/resources" 
        main.output.resourcesDir = "build/js/resources"
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use `project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.first().contains("run")`, since `taskNames` is a list with one item looking like `:MyProject:run`.