# skip prebuilt-library.mk on gradle sync android studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, gradle, ndk-build

My project app depends on a library module alib. both app and alib build a c++ library with ndk. the app c++ lib, called app.so, depends on alib.so, which is the c++ lib for the library module. Inside the android.mk of app, i have:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(the_right_alib_path)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := alibsdk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libalib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Gradle sync fails on prebuilt-library.mk, with message Android NDK: Check that /the_right_alib_path/libalib.so  exists or that its path is correct.

the file would be there if i build the module with gradle, it's naturally not there when I do gradle sync.

How can I skip the execution of prebuilt-library.mk?
Alternatively there is a way to tell ndk that the alib.so will be built by another gradle module?

Ps. This is more annoying cause in reality it checks all the libraries for different versions/flavor/dimensions, and i don't need to build all those libraries to work on the dev version on the app.

Comment: regarding your **PS**, try this lifehack: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/1GI1_zjWNAs/MCPWtJv4CQAJ

Comment: thanks Alex for the suggestion, as a workaround i currently use the touch command on console to fake the presence of the libs. Other thing to add is that i can compile fine with gradle from command line. Issue is on gradle sync on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the error by small modification of the **Android.mk**:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := alibsdk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libalib.so
ifeq ($(findstring n,$(MAKEFLAGS)),n)
  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
else
  include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
endif
```

This takes advantage of the `-n` flag that is passed to **ndk-build** during *sync*. You can create a custom define for that, if you wish. **build-shared-library.mk** will generate a warning about strange SRC, but won't fail.

Same can be achieved without touching the **Android.mk** files: in your **build.gradle**, use

```
if (project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.isEmpty()
 || project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames[0].contains(":generate")) {
  android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.ndkBuild.arguments += 'PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY=$(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)'
}
```

Android Studio runs **ndk-build** many times: with no tasks (the *Sync* step), within a *:generate[flavor][Debug|Release]Sources*, and within *:externalNativeBuild[flavor][Debug|Release]*.

To retrieve the current task, I followed *https://stackoverflow.com/a/21603707/192373*.

Maybe the easiest fix is to rely on an obscure implementation detail of **`prebuilt-library.mk`**<sup>*)</sup>. Early in your main **`Android.mk`**, add the line

```
override prebuilt=$(if $(strip $(wildcard $(prebuilt_path))),$(prebuilt_path),.)
```

This can be done in gradle, if necessary:

```
android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.ndkBuild {
   arguments 'prebuilt=$(if $(strip $(wildcard $(prebuilt_path))),$(prebuilt_path),.)'
}
```

---

***)** verified for NDK r19b and earlier.

Comment: All the solutions work (I had to change for 2nd and 3rd android.externalNativeBuild.ndkBuild.arguments to arguments and copied the snippet on the defaultConfig->externalNativeBuild->ndkBuild). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, `defaultConfig` got lost in copy/paste!