# Use separate signing keys for APK and app bundle

Tags: android, gradle

I need to build an APK signed with our app signing key for internal testing, and also build an app bundle signed with our upload key for when we submit to Google Play. How do I configure my `build.gradle` to use different keys based on whether I'm building an APK or an app bundle?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem? I'm exactly trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames`

You can access the names of the tasks to execute in the current build by using `project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21603707/23384720)). This can be useful to determine if you are currently building an APK or an AAB:

```kotlin
val keystorePropertiesFile =
    if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("bundleRelease")) {
        println("Using upload-keystore")
        file("upload-keystore.properties")
    } else {
        println("Using app-signing-keystore")
        file("app-signing-keystore.properties")
    }
val keystoreProperties= Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
```

This example follows the [Android documentation to remove signing information from your build files](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#secure-shared-keystore).

But be aware, that if you try to build both at the same time using `./gradlew assembleRelease bundleRelease`, it will use the upload-keystore for the APK too!
So you should always run both tasks separately.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to specify different `signingConfig` sections, and then reference the relevant one for each build flavor.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898611/gradle-signing-flavors-with-different-keys-on-android/40124853) for more information.

Comment: I want to build the same flavor, but use different keys based on whether I'm building an APK or an app bundle.